# How to get the Current Line Index in WinUI UWP TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I know that `SelectionStart` property of **WinUI UWP** `TextBox` will return the `CaretIndex`. But, I want to get the exact Column and Line Position of Text. In **WPF**, `GetLineFromCharacterIndex(CaretIndex)` and `TextBox.Lines[LineIndex].Length` could be used to find the Current **Line Index** and **Column number** respectively. How can I achieve the same in **WinUI UWP** `Textbox` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public static int GetCurrentLineIndex(TextBox textBox)
{
    int caretIndex = textBox.SelectionStart;
    if (caretIndex == 0)
        return 0;

    string[] lines = textBox.Text?.Split('\r') ?? Array.Empty<string>();
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = lines[i];
        offset += line.Length;
        if (caretIndex <= offset)
            return i;
        offset++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It may need some slight improvement but it should give you the idea how you could determine the current line of the cursor.

You can call it from wherever you want to get the index, e.g.:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = GetCurrentLineIndex(sender as TextBox);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This solution worked perfectly !

Comment: I got the length of currentLine to get CurrentColumnIndex. It is working like a charm when Enter/Space/BackSpace is pressed inside TextBox. But when ArrowKeys are pressed neither the rows nor the columns are getting Updated. I tried to handle TextBox.Selection_Changed event since CaretIndex=SelectionStart. But, still the lineIndex and columnIndex are not getting updated when Arrow keys are used to move the Cursor. Can you share some solution for this Problem ?

Comment: Can you provide a solution for the above problem ?

Comment: @Kris: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. And please include a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you post.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
var text = Textbox.Text;
var lines = text.Split('\r');
...
```

This has worked for me in the past using WPF but I have never tried UWP.

This also seems like a workaround so there might be a better, more practical, solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried that already in UWP. It is not working out due to some unknown reason :-(

Comment: If you set a variable to Textbox.Text, you can add a breakpoint or a watch and see what the output is (including characters like \n) so you can see what is separating the lines, it may be \r.

Comment: Ok I will try it out

Comment: I have tried it out and '\r' does the trick, I will edit my answer

Comment: Np, you can set this answer to correct so others know this works

Comment: This solution is okay. But, I need to find the Current Line Index whenever the the text gets changed. That is where the actual problem starts

Comment: Just use a TextChanged event handler and look in the new text to see what is changed. If you are using MVVM just compare the value to the private property in the setter.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses MVVM structure but you can apply the same concepts with a temp variable which stores the previous value.

```
<TextBox Height="600" Width="600" 
         Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

Then I added this to the constructor:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

This isnt best practice and if you were using MVVM you would set up a ViewModel and use that (I did this for testing purposes).

Then I created my properties like this:

```
    private int _line;

public int Line
{
    get { return _line; }
    set
    {
        _line = value;
        tb1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}

private int _column;

public int Column
{
    get { return _column; }
    set
    {
        _column = value;
        tb2.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}

private string _text;

public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        if (_text + '\r' != value)
        {
            Line = GetLine(_text, value);
            Column = GetColumn(_text, value, Line);
        }
        else
        {
            Line++;
            Column = 0;
        }

        _text = value;
    }
}
```

Then added my functions:

```
public int GetLine(string original, string newText)
{
    var oLines = GenArray(original);
    var nLines = GenArray(newText);

    //set this to -1 if you want 0-based indexing
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var line in nLines)
    {
        count++;
        if (oLines.Length < count || line != oLines[count - 1])
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public int GetColumn(string original, string newText, int lineChanged)
{
    var oLine = GenArray(original)[lineChanged - 1];
    var nLine = GenArray(newText)[lineChanged - 1];

    //set this to -1 if you want 0-based indexing
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var c in nLine)
    {
        count++;
        if (oLine.Length < count || c != oLine[count - 1])
        {

        }
    }

    return count;
}

private string[] GenArray(string text)
{
    string[] lines;
    if (text == null)
    {
        lines = new string[1] { "" };
    }
    else if (text.Contains('\r'))
    {
        lines = text.Split('\r');
    }
    else
    {
        lines = new string[1] { text };
    }

    return lines;
}
```

If you don't use MVVM just do this:

```
public string[] TempLines { get; set; }
...
//after the calculation code has finished
TempLines = TextBox.Split('\r');
```

Then you can substitute TempLines for value

Comment: I am using MVVM. I have multiple TextBoxes attached to TabViewItems of TabView. I will try your solution.Thanks for helping out :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This solution too worked !